# WCF Data Service based on EF5 Model; how to add a custom type

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, service

I am trying to build a WCF Data Service with a ServiceMethod returning a custom type.
This type is used as a container to transmit multiple data collection at once. I am not able to define this type as entity or complex type.

```
public class BrfPackageDataContainer {
  public ICollection<BrfFlight> Flights {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public ICollection<BrfFlight_Info> Flight_Infos {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public ICollection<BrfInfo> Infos {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public BrfPackageDataContainer() {
    this.Flights = new List<BrfFlight>();
    this.Flight_Infos = new List<BrfFlight_Info>();
    this.Infos = new List<BrfInfo>();
  }
}
```

This is my ServiceMethod declaration:

```
    [WebGet]
    [SingleResult]
    public FlightInfoEntities.BrfPackageDataContainer GetBrfPackage () {
        var brfPackageDataContainer = new FlightInfoEntities.BrfPackageDataContainer();
        brfPackageDataContainer.Demodata();
        return brfPackageDataContainer;
    }
```

I got this running when using an empty dummy DataService as data source for the service class definition. But when I use my Entity Framework Model as data source the service refuse to start because of the missing metadata for the custom type.
My question is:
How can I use an EF Model as data source AND still use my custom type as a return value for my method.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. When using Entity Framework only the types defined in the EF model can be used and you cannot add a custom type to your model. If complex type is enough for you you may try adding a dummy complex type to your EF model which will not be used by EF but you would use it (caveat - I have not tried this).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with a workaround:

I added 3 complex types to my modell, matching the data structure of each individual result set.
Furthermore I added a container class outside the data context which uses the complex types to hold the data in one object.
I extended the context class with a custom method to handle the stored procedure call and mapping the results to the appropriate complex types.ObjectContext.Translate helps a lot...
The WCF Data Service class is instantiated with a dummy DataContext. This enables metadata creation for my custom data container class which now can be used as return type of a custom WCF Data Service Method.
The data context is instantiated when the method is called.

Data container class`   public class BrfPackageDataContainer {
        public Guid TransactionId {
            get;
            set;
        }

```
    public List<BrfFlight> Flights {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<BrfFlight_Info> Flight_Infos {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<BrfInfo> Infos {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public BrfPackageDataContainer () {
        this.Flights = new List<BrfFlight>();
        this.Flight_Infos = new List<BrfFlight_Info>();
        this.Infos = new List<BrfInfo>();
    }
}`
```

context extension:
public partial class FlightInfoEntities
    {
        public virtual BrfPackageDataContainer GetBrfPackage(int? crewId, string operatorCode, string departure, int? flightId, DateTime? stdRangeStart,
                                                             DateTime? stdRangeEnd, string requestingApplication, string requestingComputerName,
                                                             string requestingACReg, ref Guid transactionId, int? specificInfoTypeId, byte? levelOfDetail,
                                                             bool? skipLog) {
            using (DbCommand command = this.Database.Connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetBrfPackage]";

```
            ...

            var dataContainer = new BrfPackageDataContainer();

            try {
                this.Database.Connection.Open();

                using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    dataContainer.Flights = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Translate<BrfFlight>(reader).ToList();
                    reader.NextResult();
                    dataContainer.Flight_Infos = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Translate<BrfFlight_Info>(reader).ToList();
                    reader.NextResult();
                    dataContainer.Infos = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Translate<BrfInfo>(reader).ToList();
                }
                return dataContainer;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

WCF Data Service Method:

```
    [WebGet]
    [SingleResult]
    public BrfPackageDataContainer GetBrfPackage () {
        using (var brfCtx = new FlightInfoEntities()) {
            Guid transactionId = new Guid();
            var brfPackageDataContainer = brfCtx.GetBrfPackage(null,"4T",null,null,null,null,"test",Environment.MachineName,null,ref transactionId,null,3,false);
            return brfPackageDataContainer;
        }
    }
```